# How to config putty remote port forwarding to connect mysql?

Tags: ssh, mysql, putty, tunnel

I installed `MySQL` to a Windows box. I want to connect it from a Linux box.
I run `plink` to setup a remote port forwarding in Windows box.
I try to connect it from Linux box, but it's not working.

#### Windows (192.168.1.101)

```
C:\> plink -v -N -R 3306:localhost:3306 kev@192.168.1.102 -pw ADMIN
```

Also tried `putty` with this config:

```
Port forwarding: R3306->localhost:3306
```

#### Linux (192.168.1.102)

```
$ mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

$ nc localhost 3306
J
5.5.283V6L[fnu▒▒!▒$N>-c-R9bbG{mysql_native_password
```

Comment: I believe that you are connecting to localhost via local socket, but you need to connect via localhost port, so connect with argument `mysql --protocol=TCP`.

Comment: @week Thanks. It works. Please post comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you are connecting to localhost via local socket, but you need to connect via localhost tcp port, so connect with argument `mysql --protocol=TCP`.